# Unable to modify default (simple) theme

Tags: pelican

I'm new to Pelican and am trying to modify the default theme (called simple) so suit my tastes. So I started by trying to get rid of the footer that says "Proudly powered by Pelican, which takes great advantage of Python".

So I looked things up online and went through the following steps:

- Uncommented the footer section from the file `./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pelican/themes/simple/templates/base.html`.
- Ran the command `pelican content -s pelicanconf.py -t venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pelican/themes/simple`
- Tried `make html` as well
- Viewed the site using `pelican --autoreload --listen` and reloaded the page
- Also viewed the site using `make devserver` abd reloaded the page.

However, the footer stays. Yes, I can just hide it through CSS, but that's not my goal; my goal is to learn how to modify Pelican themes.

Not sure what else I need to do!

Comment: The default theme is "notmyidea", not "simple". You're editing the wrong theme.

Comment: Damn! Is there a variable controlling the current theme?

Comment: In any case, thanks! That solved my problem. :-)

Comment: You have the `THEME` variable in your `pelicanconf.py`

Comment: I didn't have any `THEME` variable there. Maybe that's what confused me.